# Settings.xml in local maven repository

Tags: java, maven

I cannot find settings.xml in my local maven repository. Please tell me where I can find it.[image]

In my java class, I am getting compile time error for following.

[image]

I have mentioned dependency in pom.xml file also.

[image]

Please help me why dependency is not found even when pom.xml has dependencies.

Comment: Do you have the m2e plugin installed and is the source in a maven project?

Comment: Yes, I have installed m2e plugin installed and I created a Maven archtype-quickstart project.

Comment: But does _eclipse_ know that?  you should import the project as a maven project with existing sources for dependency resolution to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings.xml is ***NOT*** located in repository directory.

There are two settings.xml files that Maven will lookup automatically, one is in the Maven installation directory, and one is in `your home/.m2/`  (not `your home/.m2/repository`)

Normally we will update the one under `your home/.m2/`.  In your case, it should be located at `C:\Users\yourName\.m2\settings.xml`

Answer (score 3):

You will find settings.xml in your maven installation directory.

e.g, If you have unzipped your maven inside C:\apache-maven-3.0.4 directory then the settings.xml will be present in: C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf directory.

Answer (score 2):

There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:

- The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
- A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-settings/settings.html

E.g. (depends on your operating system)

```
%userprofile%\.m2\settings.xml
C:\Users\<YourName>\.m2\settings.xml
C:\Documents and Settings\<YourName>\.m2\settings.xml
~/.m2/settings.xml
/home/<YourName>/.m2/settings.xml
```

or

```
<MAVEN_INSTALL_DIR>/conf/settings.xml
```